# Add columns with percentages

Tags: r, dplyr

The data provided shows the count of each variable (1-10) for each district. For example, let's say the total/sum of each variable value for district 1 is `x` (100%). Now, I want to add the percentage of each categorical variable with respect to the sum of that district in new columns (10 new columns) (say `pct1`, `pct2` and etc.) for each district (so, sum of percentages of `pct1` - `pct10` would be a `100%`). I would like to do this for each district.

How can I do this?

data:

```
df = structure(list(LONGNAME = c("District 1", "District 2", "District 3", 
"District 4", "District 5", "District 6", "District 7", "District 8", 
"District 9"), `1` = c(42065L, 49367L, 37063L, 27360L, 36424L, 
26415L, 28010L, 35001L, 30510L), `2` = c(1667L, 3598L, 3989L, 
6762L, 2125L, 2660L, 3912L, 4258L, 4089L), `3` = c(6004L, 7672L, 
9245L, 10118L, 5554L, 5520L, 7853L, 8716L, 7554L), `4` = c(6712L, 
2656L, 4700L, 6868L, 2560L, 3452L, 4838L, 4656L, 3458L), `5` = c(5626L, 
4823L, 5086L, 10852L, 4700L, 4239L, 5032L, 7864L, 5623L), `6` = c(5737L, 
9123L, 10042L, 20704L, 10119L, 13243L, 11144L, 12049L, 14064L
), `7` = c(4669L, 4338L, 3859L, 12530L, 4453L, 8099L, 3658L, 
4049L, 6360L), `8` = c(2212L, 2980L, 1647L, 11298L, 4611L, 13664L, 
1139L, 2132L, 6879L), `9` = c(302L, 830L, 700L, 6476L, 675L, 
20224L, 357L, 588L, 907L), `10` = c(14L, 25L, 12L, 1087L, 6L, 
2916L, 2L, 23L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `across` to loop over the integer columns and apply `proportions`. To create the new columns, modify the `.names` by appending `pct` before the `{.col}` - stands for the column name

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(-LONGNAME, ~ proportions(.x) * 100, .names = "pct{.col}"))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 9 × 21
  LONGNAME     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  pct1  pct2  pct3  pct4  pct5  pct6  pct7  pct8   pct9   pct10
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 District 1 42065  1667  6004  6712  5626  5737  4669  2212   302    14 13.5   5.04  8.80 16.8  10.4   5.40  8.98  4.75  0.972  0.342 
2 District 2 49367  3598  7672  2656  4823  9123  4338  2980   830    25 15.8  10.9  11.2   6.66  8.96  8.59  8.34  6.40  2.67   0.611 
3 District 3 37063  3989  9245  4700  5086 10042  3859  1647   700    12 11.9  12.1  13.5  11.8   9.45  9.45  7.42  3.54  2.25   0.293 
4 District 4 27360  6762 10118  6868 10852 20704 12530 11298  6476  1087  8.76 20.5  14.8  17.2  20.2  19.5  24.1  24.3  20.9   26.6   
5 District 5 36424  2125  5554  2560  4700 10119  4453  4611   675     6 11.7   6.43  8.14  6.42  8.73  9.53  8.56  9.90  2.17   0.147 
6 District 6 26415  2660  5520  3452  4239 13243  8099 13664 20224  2916  8.46  8.05  8.09  8.65  7.87 12.5  15.6  29.3  65.1   71.3   
7 District 7 28010  3912  7853  4838  5032 11144  3658  1139   357     2  8.97 11.8  11.5  12.1   9.35 10.5   7.03  2.45  1.15   0.0489
8 District 8 35001  4258  8716  4656  7864 12049  4049  2132   588    23 11.2  12.9  12.8  11.7  14.6  11.3   7.78  4.58  1.89   0.562 
9 District 9 30510  4089  7554  3458  5623 14064  6360  6879   907     5  9.77 12.4  11.1   8.67 10.4  13.2  12.2  14.8   2.92   0.122
```

---

If we want by row, then use the margin 1

```
df[paste0("pct", names(df)[-1])] <- proportions(as.matrix(df[-1]), 1) * 100
```

-output

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 × 21
  LONGNAME     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  pct1  pct2  pct3  pct4  pct5  pct6  pct7  pct8   pct9   pct10
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 District 1 42065  1667  6004  6712  5626  5737  4669  2212   302    14  56.1  2.22  8.00  8.95  7.50  7.65  6.22  2.95  0.403 0.0187 
2 District 2 49367  3598  7672  2656  4823  9123  4338  2980   830    25  57.8  4.21  8.98  3.11  5.65 10.7   5.08  3.49  0.972 0.0293 
3 District 3 37063  3989  9245  4700  5086 10042  3859  1647   700    12  48.5  5.23 12.1   6.16  6.66 13.2   5.05  2.16  0.917 0.0157 
4 District 4 27360  6762 10118  6868 10852 20704 12530 11298  6476  1087  24.0  5.93  8.87  6.02  9.51 18.2  11.0   9.91  5.68  0.953  
5 District 5 36424  2125  5554  2560  4700 10119  4453  4611   675     6  51.1  2.98  7.80  3.59  6.60 14.2   6.25  6.47  0.948 0.00842
6 District 6 26415  2660  5520  3452  4239 13243  8099 13664 20224  2916  26.3  2.65  5.50  3.44  4.22 13.2   8.06 13.6  20.1   2.90   
7 District 7 28010  3912  7853  4838  5032 11144  3658  1139   357     2  42.5  5.93 11.9   7.34  7.63 16.9   5.55  1.73  0.541 0.00303
8 District 8 35001  4258  8716  4656  7864 12049  4049  2132   588    23  44.1  5.37 11.0   5.87  9.91 15.2   5.10  2.69  0.741 0.0290 
9 District 9 30510  4089  7554  3458  5623 14064  6360  6879   907     5  38.4  5.15  9.51  4.35  7.08 17.7   8.01  8.66  1.14  0.00629
> rowSums(df[-(1:11)])
[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Comment: Yup, the second method is what I was looking for, if it's not much can you please explain what is `names(df)[-1])` and `as.matrix(df[-1]), 1` doing?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy The `names(df)[-1]` select the column names other than the first column name as it is `LONGNAME` which is a string.  The `as.matrix` is needed as `proportions` expect either a vector, matrix or `data.frame`.  Your data is a `tibble` which doesn't have a method in `proportions`.  So either `as.matrix(df[-1])` or `as.data.frame(df[-1])` should work

Comment: Can you please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74804272/add-columns-by-percentages-by-city). It's almost the same data however, I am still getting an error with method 2.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy I guess the comment below that question solves your issue